# [VBA]Chart location referring to set-worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to embed the chart to the variable that i had already set as worksheet.
but it couldn't run properly. I'm not sure if the statement was correct.

```
Public DataSheet As Worksheet
Public Graph As Chart
Public Cat_3, Cat_4, Cat_5 As Range

Set DataSheet = Worksheets("DataSheets")
Set Cat_3 = DataSheet.Range("c2:c16")

Set Graph = Charts.Add
Graph.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
Graph.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Cat_3
Set Graph = Graph.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=DataSheet)
```

I am getting an error on the last, any suggestions on that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
Graph.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=DataSheet.Name
```

moreover you may want to use a more robust syntax like follows:

```
Set Graph = Charts.Add
With Graph
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Cat_3
    .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=DataSheet.Name
End With
```